# Get a XML by using AJAX then parse it into JSON (without server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, xml

I asking for help to a little code that I'm working on.
But I'm not good with AJAX and Jquery... So here's my topic : I wanted to get a XML with a external XML file (here text.xml) and parse it into a JSON object with the the code of David Walsh (source here : https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json ).
Then someone said the function can only be in the "success" part that's why I'm doig all my function on it.
So my goal is to have my XML into JSON object that i can treat it easier, I find some forum topic that answer to my question but my code aren't working and I don't why... If you can help me thank you.
There is my code :

```
 <HTML>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>testSelection</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <body>
        <div id="Div_XML"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var xml = $.parseXML('<bds> <serie1 id="1"> <desc> <num> 2 </num><title>we are on 1 </title><commen>HI </commen><URL>Idk</URL></desc><desc><num> 1 </num><title>we are on  2 </title><commen>Hello world </commen><URL>Baptiste</URL></desc></serie1></bds>')
        var results = new Array;
        var obj = {};


        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "text.xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: function(xml) {

                                var commen = $(this).find('commen').text();
                                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                                var URL = $(this).find('URL').text();
                                var num = $(this).find('num').text();

                                $(xml).find('bds').each(

                                    function() {
                                        results.push({
                                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                                            num: num,
                                            commen: commen,
                                            title: title,
                                            URL: URL});
                                        });
                                        // Changes XML to JSON


                                            // Create the return object
                                         function parseX(results){    

                                            if (results.nodeType == 1) { // element
                                                // do attributes
                                                if (results.attributes.length > 0) {
                                                    obj["@attributes"] = {};
                                                    for (var j = 0; j < results.attributes.length; j++) {
                                                        var attribute = results.attributes.item(j);
                                                        obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } else if (results.nodeType == 3) { // text
                                                obj = results.nodeValue;
                                            }

                                            // do children
                                            if (results.hasChildNodes()) {
                                                for (var i = 0; i < results.childNodes.length; i++) {
                                                    var item = results.childNodes.item(i);
                                                    var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                                                    if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                                                        obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
                                                    } else {
                                                        if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                                                            var old = obj[nodeName];
                                                            obj[nodeName] = [];
                                                            obj[nodeName].push(old);

                                                        }
                                                        obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }



                                        // Assuming xmlDoc is the XML DOM Document
                                        var jsonText = JSON.stringify(xmlToJson(results));
                                        alert(jsonText);
                                        }
                                        }
                                    )
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    )
    </script>
</body>

</HTML>
```

So my idea was to push in an array all of my xml data then parse it into json.
So I have questions  :

- -Can you gave to the code of David Walsh an array ?
- -Can we do more than one function into the success part of AJAX ?
- -Can my JSON object can be split by series ? (i give the xml just after you will see serie1, serie2, serie3)
- -Can I compare the num (Json object) with numbers ?  ( like text.num == 1 for exemple)

Sorry for my beginner questions...

And the text.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<bds>
        <serie1 id="1">
                <desc>
                        <num> 1 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 1 </title>
                        <commen>Hello </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 2 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 2 </title>
                        <commen>HI </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 3 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 3 </title>
                        <commen>How are you  </commen>
                        <URL>Gars inconnu</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 4 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 4 </title>
                        <commen>Idk  </commen>
                        <URL>Raymond</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 5 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 5 </title>
                        <commen>Thank you </commen>
                        <URL>Eric</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 6 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 6 </title>
                        <commen>You're welcome  </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 7 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 7 </title>
                        <commen>Sorry </commen>
                        <URL>CÃ©line</URL>
                </desc>
        </serie1>
            <serie2 id="2">
                <desc>
                        <num> 1 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 1 </title>
                        <commen>Hello </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 2 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 2 </title>
                        <commen>HI </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 3 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 3 </title>
                        <commen>How are you  </commen>
                        <URL>Gars inconnu</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 4 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 4 </title>
                        <commen>Idk  </commen>
                        <URL>Raymond</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 5 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 5 </title>
                        <commen>Thank you </commen>
                        <URL>Eric</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 6 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 6 </title>
                        <commen>You're welcome  </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 7 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 7 </title>
                        <commen>Sorry </commen>
                        <URL>CÃ©line</URL>
                </desc>
        </serie2>
            <serie3 id="3">
                <desc>
                        <num> 1 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 1 </title>
                        <commen>Hello </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 2 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 2 </title>
                        <commen>HI </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 3 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 3 </title>
                        <commen>How are you  </commen>
                        <URL>Gars inconnu</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 4 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 4 </title>
                        <commen>Idk  </commen>
                        <URL>Raymond</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 5 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 5 </title>
                        <commen>Thank you </commen>
                        <URL>Eric</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 6 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 6 </title>
                        <commen>You're welcome  </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 7 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 7 </title>
                        <commen>Sorry </commen>
                        <URL>CÃ©line</URL>
                </desc>
        </serie3>
</bds>
```

I was using the var xml to do test in local and it work but when I need to get the XML from a file I'm completely lost.
Then I don't use JSON at the begining instead of XML beacause I want later for my project to write into it and I read it's not possible in JSON...
By the way I can't using XmlHTTPRequest and PHP, i know that would be the  better and easier way to do it...
Hope you have an answer to my question and thank you for your reading.

Comment: `parseX(results)` function definition should be outside of the `success` function so that you can call `parseX` function anywhere you like and you need the pass XML object instead `results object` that you created.

Comment: So I need to add the function parseX not into the success part ? I see, then I will gave it the array results. I will try thank you

Comment: Every time that said me SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Any idea what I can do to debug that error ?

Comment: yes you need to keep `parseX` function as separate and `parseX` internally calling `xmlToJson` you need modify it to `parseX` as well.

Comment: after success function extra curly braces(`}`) are added and closing brackets (`)`) is missing for `$.ajax`

Comment: Oh thank you ! I didn't notice !

Answer (score 0):

So I let AJAX down, use this instead :

```
    // File: readXML.js

var i; 
var LinkNum = new Array;
var LinkCommen = new Array ;
var LinkURL = new Array;
var LinkTitle = new Array; 
var tab = new Array; 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Open the students.xml file
    $.get("text.xml",{},function(xml){

        // Build an HTML string
        myHTMLOutput = '';
        myHTMLOutput += '<table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        myHTMLOutput += '<th>LinkTitle</th><th>LinkCommen</th><th>LinkURL</th><th>LinkNum</th>';

        // Run the function for each student tag in the XML file

        $('bds',xml).each(function() {

            $(this).children().each(function(){

                $(this).children().each(function() {

                    LinkNum.push($(this).children("num").text());
                    LinkCommen.push( $(this).children("commen").text());
                    LinkURL.push($(this).children("URL").text());
                    LinkTitle.push($(this).children("title").text());

                });


            });

            // Build row HTML data and store in string
                mydata = BuildStudentHTML(LinkNum,LinkCommen,LinkURL,LinkTitle);
                myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;
        });
        myHTMLOutput += '</table>';

        // Update the DIV called Content Area with the HTML string
        $("#ContentArea").append(myHTMLOutput);
    });
});



 function BuildStudentHTML(LinkNum,LinkCommen,LinkURL,LinkTitle){

    // Check to see if their is a "post" attribute in the name field
    // Build HTML string and return
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    if (LinkNum[i]==6) 
    {
    output = '';
    output += '<tr>';
    output += '<td>'+ LinkTitle[i] +'</td>';
    output += '<td>'+ LinkCommen[i] +'</td>';
    output += '<td>'+ LinkURL[i] +'</td>';
    output += '<td>'+ LinkNum[i] +'</td>';
    output += '</tr>';
        return output;
    }

    }
}
```

Source here : http://www.compoc.com/tuts/

So basically I return my node in an Array, for now I got a little problem for take the second and third serie of my XML but i retrieved what I wrote on my xml.
PS : I just use in the function LinkNum == 6 just for testing, I have just now parsed them on different array to treat them after.